# Magento 2 : session doesn't work?

Tags: magento-2.1.9

I try using session variable in my custom module on Magento 2.1.9 Enterprise Edition, cloud version.
When i post my form, i can set and display session variable in my controller. But when i quit the page, go back and display session variable, it's empty...

My controller code is :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\VendorModule\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

/** @var  \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic */
protected $_genericSession;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                            \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $genericSession
                            )
{
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_genericSession = $genericSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
public function execute()
{
    // Form submit
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if ($post && count($post) > 0) {

        $this->_genericSession->setRX($post);

    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($this->_genericSession->getRX());
    echo "</pre>";

    // Add page title
    $resultPageFactory = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Page title'));

    // Add breadcrumb
    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs */
    $breadcrumbs = $resultPageFactory->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');     
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home',
        [
            'label' => __('Home'),
            'title' => __('Home'),
            'link' => $this->_url->getUrl('')
        ]
    );

    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('explore-breadcrumbs',
        [
            'label' => __('Page title'),
            'title' => __('Page title')
        ]
    );

    return $resultPageFactory;
    }
}
?>
```

It seems many topics on the web about session problem. Is there really a problem 
 with session ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\VendorModule\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

/** @var  \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic */
    protected $_genericSession;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                                CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
            CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
            SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
                                )
    {
            $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
            $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
            $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // Form submit
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($post && count($post) > 0) {
            //To set Cookie
             $duration = '86400';

             $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
                ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                ->setDuration($duration)
                ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
                ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

            $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
                'post_data',
                $post,
                $metadata
            );

        }

       //To get Cookie
        $get_data = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie('post_data');
        print_r($get_data);
        die();


        // Add page title
        $resultPageFactory = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Page title'));

        // Add breadcrumb
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs */
        $breadcrumbs = $resultPageFactory->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');     
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home',
            [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Home'),
                'link' => $this->_url->getUrl('')
            ]
        );

        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('explore-breadcrumbs',
            [
                'label' => __('Page title'),
                'title' => __('Page title')
            ]
        );

        return $resultPageFactory;
        }
    }
?>
```

If this answer is really helpful means please accept the answer this will helpful for others...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but problem is always the same

Comment: Is that saving or not?

Comment: Data was saving but if i change page and go back, print_r($get_data) is empty

Comment: I can able to get that variable in all the pages I want. I think you're doing some mistake... Using this code I got the session variable on the checkout page.  Please check once again. I don't understand that go back page let me explain clearly to fix this

Comment: ok, i will try to be clearer. I go to the page http://myproject.com/fr_fr/mypage1/ where the controller code you suggest me runs. I submit form, page is reloading and cookie post_data is displaying. I quit this page to go to  http://myproject.com/fr_fr/mypage2/. I go back to http://myproject.com/fr_fr/mypage1/.  So post_data is displaying but this cookie/session variable is now empty.

Answer (score 0):

For information, i found a solution : disabled cache with layout :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Vendor\VendorModule\Block\Mypage1" name="vendormodule.mypage1" template="Vendor_VendorModule::mypage1.phtml" cacheable="false" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Thanks for your help